# Not able to display the url for resized image in php

Tags: php, html, image

I am able to resize with the help of code using libraries in php.But i am not able to display the url for resized image web page.I am resizing the image first and then i want to display the url for resized image.
I am able to display the image but not the url of resized image.Please tell me how can i display the url for modified image by looking at code below

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
//echo $width;
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source,0,0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
echo imagejpeg($thumb);



?>
```

Comment: I am not sure to follow here, the url of the image you are resizing here must be the url of the script itself. You are here effectively displaying the resized image.

Comment: yes.i m displaying the image as of now.But i m not able to get to display the url of resized one may b because I dont know much about copyresized function.Please help me on this

Comment: It looks to me like this function doesn't write the URL of the resized image anywhere permanent. It looks like it just puts it somewhere temporary for streaming out to the client, and (hopefully) cleans up after itself by deleting an temporary files. Don't know for sure ...

Comment: if your script is called "imageResized.php" then this is the url of the resized image, because it is the url of the script that is displaying the resized image. The resized image although doesn't exist physically until you write imagejpeg($thumb) output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't saved the resized image anywhere, so unless you save it somewhere you can only get the resized image from this script's url.
To save the image just specify a name to `imagejpeg`

```
// save
imagejpeg($thumb,'test-sm.jpg');
//Output
readfile('test-sm.jpg');
```

the url of the image will be the current directory + the name you saved it as.

Comment: But there are multiple images which we have to resize may b in multiples of 100000s.So it wnt be a better idea to save them one by one at server.M i ryt?

Comment: You have two options. 1. Run a job to resize them all. 2. Resize them on the fly(either temporarily or permanently) when requested.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the script you posted was `imageResized.php`
then the other page would have:

```
<img src="imageResized.php" />
```

Comment: It is, obviously this will always load `test.jpg` as its hardcoded. if you want to make it variable then it'd be `<img src="imageResized.php?filename=whatever.jpg" />` but don't forget to filter the request param to prevent random downloading of files

Comment: I am able to display the url of page with curpageurl() script.But when i use the url coming from this function which is the web page url in image tag.Its not displaying the imagee infact its showing blank.

Comment: the above will only work with a php script that outputs an image, like in your post

Comment: It means there the resized url of the image is the web page url with which we are displaying the image.But how can we write the url then

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what your looking for, the url of the image is the url of the php file that produces the image. eg `http://yoursite.com/path/to/imageResized.php`

Comment: I got your point that page url is url of resized image.But when i put that page url in <img src> tag ,it doesnot show any image.Thats the problem.Is it like that it will not work in img tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

from http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php to get the script name. The URL you request of the server is going to be the URL for the image.

However, you won't be able to display this in the browser as in this call, as this script is just getting the image. You can use this code to get the URL to write to a log file.